# How to add a patch on a Wind rose?

Tags: matplotlib, patch, wedge

I am using the following code to add a patch (a Wedge) over a Wind rose...however the output also provided is not looking good... Would anyone have solution to my problem?

```
fov = Wedge((0,0), 20, 20, 60, color="r", alpha=0.5)

plt.hist([0, 1])
plt.close()


ax=WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.grid(linestyle="dashed", color="grey", zorder=0)
ax.bar(df_1995['dir'], df_1995['w_speed'],normed=True, opening=1, cmap = cm.magma_r, edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.5, bins=spd_bins, nsector=36, zorder= 3)
ax.set_legend(loc=(-0.12, 0.75), labels=spd_labels)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(1, 12, step=3))
ax.set_yticklabels(np.arange(1, 12, step=3))
ax.set_title("Walney, Pre-farm Windrose")

ax.add_artist(fov)


plt.show()
```

[image: see output here]

Comment: A wedge in cartesian coordinates look a little peculiar in polar coordinates. Try using a bar instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem involves to use the following argument when defining the Wedge patch: transform=ax.transAxes

Thus, the full code for defining the patch is:

```
fov = Wedge((0.51,0.43), 0.497, 220, 260, lw=1.5, facecolor="grey", edgecolor ='black', transform=ax.transAxes, alpha=0.2)
```

[image: Updating my initial code, I get the following result:]